# Why is Scala's Range a data structure instead of a function?

Tags: scala

I come from a background in languages such as Python and R, both of which have `range()` functions which return that language's common collection type (Python's `range()` returns a list, while R's `range()` returns a vector).

So it's pretty surprising to me that Scala offers `Range`, not as a function, but as a data type. Even more surprising, `Range` is not simply an alias for a more common collections type such as `List` or `Vector`, but is an independent data type of its own!

Could someone please explain the reasoning what part of Scala's design philosophy led to `Range` being a unique data type?

Comment: Note that Python's `range` only produces a list in Python 2. In Python 3 it's a data type very much like Scala's.

Comment: See also: [scala ranges versus lists performance on large collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027801/scala-ranges-versus-lists-performance-on-large-collections)

Comment: Why is this surprising to you? In practice is there a difference between the two? Guava comes with a [`Range`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/RangesExplained) type for Java. In general you should expect different language to make different design decisions.

Answer (score 2):

## Differences between `Range` and `List`

`Range` and `List` are two different concepts, so they are implemented as two different classes in Scala. `List` is particular implementation of a sequence of values. Those can be any values in any order. On the other hand `Range` is an implementation of ordered sequence of `Int`s, that can be described by three `Int`s: `start`, `end` and `step` (starting value, end value and a step size).

`List(1, 4, 7, 10, 13)` represent the same thing as `Range(1, 14, 3)`, but differently. The main advantage of `Range` over `List` used as range, is that 
`Range` is more memory efficient. `List` used as range keeps in memory all integers in that range, where `Range` keeps in memory only the values of `start`, `end` and `step`.

> Ranges are represented in constant space, because they can be defined
>   by just three numbers: their start, their end, and the stepping value.
>   Because of this representation, most operations on ranges are
>   extremely fast.  [[source](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-immutable-collection-classes#ranges)]

You can convert `Range` to `List` by calling `toList` on it (or `toVector`/`toArray` to convert it to corresponding collection type).

## Creating `Range` by calling method

In Scala the preferred way of creating `Range`s is to call `to`, `until` and `by` methods (defined in `scala.runtime.RichInt` and `Range` classes):

```
val r1: Range = 1 to 10       // range from 1 to 10 including 1 and 10  with step size 1
val r2: Range = 1 until 10    // range from 1 to 10 including 1 but not 10  with step size 1
val r3: Range = 1 to 10 by 3  // range from 1 to 10 including 1 and 10 with step size 3
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Why not have a function that returns a list

Like Python 3's `range` (and Python 2's `xrange`), Scala's `Range` is an iterable structure that only generates the elements of the range on-demand and does not actually store them in memory. This is preferable to lists for big ranges as storing those in memory will consume a lot of memory, often for no benefit as most uses of ranges do not require the elements to be stored in memory. That's also why Python introduced `xrange` and then later replaced the old `range` with it.

#### So why not have a function the returns a `Seq` or the like

You can ask a `Range` what its starting value, it's end and it's step-size are. You couldn't do that if it were just a `Seq`.